# How to understand at which line/method to check for below C# exception?

Tags: c#, android, exception, xamarin, stack-trace

I'm a rookie in this field so have no idea how crashes/exceptions can be fixed. I have seen questions with similar error message but those had pieces of code as well; thus those people had clear idea where to look into. But here all I have is a stacktrace and have no idea in which method to start.

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.:Source:mscorlib:StackTrace:  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[TKey,TValue].MoveNext () [0x00016] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders+<GetEnumerator>d__19.MoveNext () [0x000ac] in <609d052db9cf4644bbd3271148e63c5f>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders.AddHeaders (System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders headers) [0x00025] in <609d052db9cf4644bbd3271148e63c5f>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000be] in <609d052db9cf4644bbd3271148e63c5f>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request) [0x00008] in <609d052db9cf4644bbd3271148e63c5f>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync (System.Uri requestUri) [0x0000c] in <609d052db9cf4644bbd3271148e63c5f>:0 
  at Tom.Arsene.Data.RestClient+<GetAsync>d__11`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00090] in <1f81a31c6d47431bab8f6adc642df7b4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at Tom.Arsene.Data.ArseneServiceAgent+<GetArsene>d__2.MoveNext () [0x000c3] in <1f81a31c6d47431bab8f6adc642df7b4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at Tom.Arsene.Business.ArseneService+<GetArsene>d__15.MoveNext () [0x00145] in <1f81a31c6d47431bab8f6adc642df7b4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <1bdfc850d6954268ba9a73eeb78e5ccf>:0 
  at Tom.Droid.PushHandlerService+<>c__DisplayClass20_0+<<ProcessActiveSilentNotification>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x00078] in <b12c833322824aa0abff3963b0b59352>:0
```

As I did an initial research, this exception is caused when we try to modify a collection within foreach loop in which it is being enumerated. But there is no foreach loop in ProcessActiveSilentNotification from where this seems to have originated.

I am sorry if it sounds annoying, but please help me out. This might look like just another duplicate question to you, but a solution/hint could get me proper sleep. Thanks

Comment: HttpRequestHeaders.AddHeaders via Tom.Arsene.Data.RestClient

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you please let me know how you identified this method is causing problem? Also, AddHeaders is not a written code in the solution but it's in the library. So we can't put a fix there I suppose..

Comment: When you are iterating a collection, do not modify the index of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Ah this one.

**Background:** You got the core right: [foreach and some other code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) does not work with collections. It only works with Enumerators. While any collection can be turned into a Enumerator and is implicitly, Enumerators have stricter rules then plain old collections. And one of the core rules for Enumerators created from Collections is: If the underlying collection is changed, any [Enumerator using it must invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx#Remarks). This rule is as important as Dispose and Finalize.

**Most likely cause:** You are trying to modify a collection while other code (one you wrote or one you use) is working on it via Enumerators.

It could be code that was always there, but was simply cut out by the JiT because it lacked the output so it was deemed "dead code". Like in this example trying to run into the 2 GiB Limit on a x32 System:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OOM_32_forced
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //each short is 2 byte big, Int32.MaxValue is 2^31.
            //So this will require a bit above 2^32 byte, or 2 GiB
            short[] Array = new short[Int32.MaxValue];

            /*need to actually access that array
            Otherwise JIT compiler and optimisations will just skip
            the array definition and creation */
            foreach (short value in Array)
                Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

If you cut out the output, there is a decent chance the JiT will cut out the Array definition and creation, reducing actuall use of the application to nothing. And thus effectively preventing the exception I am trying to force here.

A simple way around running into such risks, is cloning. You just create a seperate Collection and hand that one off to whatever code you have there. If a shallow copy will do or a deep clone is nesseary depends on wich type you are using. For inmutable types (most building Structs/primitive types and string) shallow copy might be enough. Of course if you can even do cloning depends on what you are even doing.

There is only so much we can tell you if you do not show us any code.